# How to install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 4.0.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I have a Rails 4 project and use `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`. The [readme installation](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#installation) suggests:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.0.0'
```

However, `bundle install` returns:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 4.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

[rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) show the latest version as `3.2.12`. How can I `bundle install` version `~> 4.0.0` as `3.2.12` only supports ActiveRecord 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just Source version `4.0.0` of `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` directly from `Github`.

In `Gemfile`

Replace

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.0.0'
```

With

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.0.0', :git => "git://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git"
```

Comment: Good solution Kirti. Implemented it, but now have a dependecies issue I cant' solve: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "arel":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 4.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      arel (~> 4.0.1) x86-mingw32

    arel (4.0.0)   I tried to remove activerecord, remove arel 4.0.0, install arel 4.0.1, and then activerecord : the result is still the same. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: As per the error there is some issue with the version of `gem arel`. Its not compatible with `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem. What is the version specified for `gem arel` in your Gemfile? Are you using Rails 4.0?

Comment: Hi Kirti, Arel is 4.0.1, RoR is 4.0 ... still searching for a solution !

Answer (score 0):

They have not provided support for Rails 4 yet, you can try below [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/sic-activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) to obtain same thing.

```
sudo gem install sic-activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
```

This will work with Rails 4 definitely, i have tried this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It says that the adapter is missing.
You should install `ruby-odbc` and it should work.

```
gem 'ruby-odbc', '0.99995'
```